# Why do I get null after using ->value (php / xpath / xml query)?

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml, xpath

I did a query of my xml file. I now want to save the result (ids) to a json file.

The problem is as a result I get:

> "user": { "0": "Michael" }

But I need:

> "user": "Michael"

The code I am using is:

```
$ids = [];

$idAttributes = $xmlfile->xpath("myquery...");
foreach ($idAttributes as $idAttribute) {

    $ids[] = $idAttribute[0]; 
}

print_r("My output : " . $ids[0]);

$user1 = $ids[0];
$user2 = $ids[1];
$user3 = $ids[2];
```

I tried also $idAttribute->value. To get only the name which I can save then to my json. But I get null only... When I print the id. I get it in the correct way, "Tom", for example. How can I save it only as "Tom" and not as
"user": { "0": "Michael" } ?

## UPDATE

```
IDs var_dump: 

string(14) "The IDS: Array" string(19) " 

ID i : " string(14) "The IDS: Array" string(19) " 
ID i : " string(14) "The IDS: Array" string(19) " 
ID i : " 

My output : Bill
```

Comment: Can you please share the content if `$ids` after the for loop with `var_dump`?

Comment: @DavidWinder I updated it now. Please have a look. After I print it I get Bill, but after I save it it is formated like described. :(

Comment: It’s really unclear what we’re supposed to be looking at here in that debug output.

Comment: My only question is how to get out of ids[0] the output "Michael" and not { "0": "Michael" }. I tried also ids[0]['0'] but I get the same. @deceze When I print the ids[0] it prints only Michael, but saves it into my json formated as { "0": "Michael" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String cast the value `(string) $idAttribute[0];` :

```
$ids = [];

$idAttributes = $xmlfile->xpath("myquery...");
foreach ($idAttributes as $idAttribute) {

    $ids[] = (string) $idAttribute[0]; 
}

print_r("My output : " . $ids[0]);

$user1 = $ids[0];
$user2 = $ids[1];
$user3 = $ids[2];
```

Every node in SimpleXML is an object. It has a [__toString](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) method to convert it to a string.

If you use `print`/`echo` to that object: it also shows the "string" value, not the current real state, being an object. Use `print_r` or `var_dump` to see it correctly.